# What's the difference between xxx(JNIEnv *env, jobject thisObj) and xxx(JNIEnv *env, jclass cls)?

Tags: java, java-native-interface

I saw some jni signatures as the following:

```
// jni
// WAY-1
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_test_Test_testMethod(JNIEnv *env,  jobject thisObj);

// WAY-2
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_test_Test_testMethod(JNIEnv *env, jclass cls);
```

And the java code maybe like this:

```
// java
package com.test;

public class Test {
    public native void testMethod(); 
}
```

What's the difference between **WAY-1** and **WAY-2** ?

Comment: You saw them where? Only the one with `jobject` is correct for this Java code.

Comment: The signatures that you see should be generated from `javah`. So, try it on the .class file from: `public class Test { public static void staticMethod(); public void instanceMethod(); }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second call signature (WAY-2) is used for `static` methods, which do not have an object instance.

Comment: That's weird. The native method "testMethod" is not static in java, but it works fine indeed.  Could you please explain more detail ? Thanks.

Comment: `jobject` and `jclass` are both pointer types, so the code will most likely work fine regardless of which one you use. But it makes no sense to use WAY-2 here since the second parameter will be an object reference and not a class reference, so by using WAY-2 you'd just be confusing anyone reading the code.

Comment: So the compiler will not check the type? @Michael

Comment: The C++ compiler has nothing to check against, since it doesn't look at your Java code. At runtime the symbol `Java_com_test_Test_testMethod` must exist in the library, but the JVM will just assume that it takes whatever arguments you specified in your Java declaration (it _is_ possible to give your JNI functions more verbose names that also includes the argument types, but that still excludes the implicit arguments, i.e. the `JNIEnv*` and the `jclass`/`jobject`).

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. @Michael